# What vpn's are currently blocking turn/stun protocols and how to work around it

Tags: vpn, webrtc

Basically what the title said, is there a list of vpn's that are blocking turn/stun protocols ? and how do we work around that ? some eastern-europe countries use vpn to access websites and use webrtc with turnservers, this can result in bad experience when on online calls.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Superuser. Apologies but I voted to close this question because it (a) in asking for a list it amounts to a shopping recommendation and (b) It appears to be confusing NAT and protocol limitations with VPN limitations (its unlikely vpns block stun/turn, its likely a connection tracking/relatrd port ussue). I posit a likely solution would be to get a VPN with a static IP - this would alleviate the 1:many nat issues and port tracking/forwarding issues I posit are the root cause of your problem.

Comment: @davidgo i actually contacted some vpn providers, and they confrmed the blocking of stun/turn protocols, can you please elaborate on where the confusion is happening ?

Comment: VPNs acts at a lower level then STUN and TURN.  (the latter run on top of the VPN, which does not really care about the traffic traversing it).     I don't know why a VPN provider - typically people in the business of routing around blocks would add a block - ie to block it would be contrary to their business model.  I can see how NAT used by VPN providers could break STUN/TURN, but this is not the same as the VPN providers blocking it - rather its a case of them not adding support for tracking and handling it.   A static IP alleviates this problem.